# Clamp is less than it's minimum value

Tags: css

I am using clamp to create a sidebar which would break at small sizes (this site is designed for desktop only, mobile users will need to scroll but this is a personal project for some friends and no-one is concerned about that)
For some reason the width is lower than the minimum value of clamp at small sizes
`width: clamp(275px, calc((100% - 160px) / 5), 400px);`
When looking at computed values in firefox this is the result:
[image: A screenshot from the firefox inspector. On the left is the CSS reading ".thin { width: clamp(275px, calc((100% - 160px) / 5), 400px); }". On the right is the computed result reading "width: 352px; clamp(275px, 20% - 32px, 400px)"]
The values on the left are applied css and values on the right are computed values.

Comment: many reasons can lead to this. We need to see the code to tell you which one

Comment: @TemaniAfif what kinds of things could cause it to break? (The way this element specifically is implemented makes it a bit hard to show, though the only css on the element is the width. It is a child of a flexbox and is added through javascript if that helps?)